# Capture all function calls using the python3 re module

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

Well I have this string and pattern :

```
s = '''double factorial ( double n ) { if ( n == 0 ) { return 1 ; } if ( n == 1 ) {     return factorial(n - 2 + 1) ; } return n * factorial ( n - 1 ) ; }'''
l = re.findall(r"{ .*(factorial\s*\(.*\))", s)
```

Intent is to match **all** fn calls i.e just the factorial(args) part. How do I modify the above so that the list 'l' returns all the relevant matches?

('l' is currently ['factorial ( n - 1 )'] which is just the last match, after findall returns)

Comment: Why did you include `{ .*` in the pattern?

Comment: You need a parser to handle this problem in the general case.  Regex alone doesn't cope well with nested content, such as code.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I was trying to match after the opening braces of the function body, it may not be needed ig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
\bfactorial\s*\([^()]*\)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/RpyGUX/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  factorial                'factorial'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```